# HasActivityInjector can not be resolved in android dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I was trying to implement **HasActivityInjector** in my android application but it's showing me HasActivityInjector cann't be resolved. Below dependencies and plugin I have used in my project-

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
```

Here is the code I am trying -

```
class RanoBoilerplateApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector{
    @Inject
    lateinit var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector:
            DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> =
            activityDispatchingAndroidInjector
}
```

I don't know what other dependencies I must have to include to work that, help me if anyone have done this before.

Find the latest Dagger 2 version [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases).

Happy coding :-)

Comment: update your version to 2.17 and rebuild project.

Comment: @UmangBurman, I am already using the latest one dependency only.

Comment: @rekire, Of course I am Importing the mentioned class, by the way I am using Android stdio, and it's cool enough to import it self or easy by Alt+Enter

Answer (score 89):

In case anyone comes here after updating to `2.24`, this was removed: https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/3bd8f707cb28fd0c5f3abb4f87658566f8b52c10.

You can use `HasAndroidInjector` instead.

Comment: As it is of any type. So, we can use the same to inject Worker as well. is it?

Comment: Lol, or when you tried using `HasAndroidInjector` below `2.24` ... D:

Answer (score 47):

It's pretty late to answer but it might be useful for someone who is new to dagger world!

Its been replaced with HasAndroidInjector in order to avoid boilerplate of implementing multiple Dagger Interfaces like HasActivityInjector, HasServiceInjector etc, in your Application class. Now you only need to implement HasAndroidInjector like below:

```
class DaggerExampleApplication : Application(), HasAndroidInjector{

       @Inject lateinit var androidInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

       override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector
       override fun onCreate() {
         super.onCreate()
         //Your code
       }        
}
```

Comment: I'm glad, you found it useful. :)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to @mbonnin and @Subhan's answer, starting version 2.24, `Has{Activity,Fragment,Service,ContentProvider,BroadcastReceiver}` are removed.
If you still want to support this old implementation, use version 2.23 which supports both `HasAndroidInjector` and `Has{Activity,Fragment,Service,ContentProvider,BroadcastReceiver}`.

here's what it should look like on version 2.24

Application

```
class ExampleApp: Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

/..../
```

Activity

```
class ExampleActivity: AppCompatActivity(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

/..../
```

Fragment

```
class MoreFragment: Fragment(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

/..../
```

Answer (score 6):

My dependencies looks like this:

```
//Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${libs.dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${libs.dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${libs.dagger}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${libs.dagger}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${libs.dagger}"
```

The `support` one is needed if you're using appcompat.
And the `${libs.dagger}` refers to the needed dagger version (e.g. 2.16).
Read more about dependencies [here](https://github.com/google/dagger#android-gradle).

Comment: could you briefly explain which dependency for what?

Comment: @BajrangHudda, briefly -  the 1st and 4th is min required for dagger to work (dagger classes + annotation processor), the 2nd and 5th are the one needed to work with `Android` (and the 3rd one if you have appcompat).

Answer (score 2):

`HasActivityInjector` was introduced in new dagger android support module.Include following dependency in your **build.gradle** file.

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.18"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.18"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could have been late late answer but new Dagger2 dependencies carries `DaggerAppCompatActivity` and `DaggerFragment` classes which are useful for injecting activities and fragments by itself. So, we no longer need `HasActivityInjector`, autoInjection methods or something like them.

Comment: We still might depend on some our legacy project or external library which force us to extend their own ```Fragment``` and ```Activity``` classes. Interfaces bring more flexibility to this.