# Cannot find symbol newDispatchingAndroidInjector during dagger update in android app

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a working Android application that uses dagger `2.21` for dependency injection. I saw that version `2.27` was available and I try to update to it.

After update of gradle dependencies there was an issue that `HasActivityInjector` couldn't be resolved. I changed implementation from this one

```kotlin
class MyApplication : ConfigApplication(), HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityInjector
    // ....
}
```

To this one as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628618/3457177)

```kotlin
class MyApplication : ConfigApplication(), HasAndroidInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>
    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector
    // ....
}
```

The problem is when I try to build my application dagger fails with the message in its generated code

> error: cannot find symbol
>       return DispatchingAndroidInjector_Factory.newDispatchingAndroidInjector(
>                                                ^
>     symbol:   method newDispatchingAndroidInjector(Map,Provider>>,Map>>)
>     location: class DispatchingAndroidInjector_Factory

Any ideas what is still missing?

Answer (score 2):

make sure you update all of this dependencies to 2.27

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger"
```